# Why is Postman returning HTML with a error rather than the data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman

I have the following index.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
require('./db/mongoose');
const User = require('./models/user');
const Task = require('./models/task');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/users', (req, res) =>{
    const user = new User(req.body);

    user.save().then(() => {
        res.status(201).send(user);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    });
});

app.post('/tasks', (req, res) => {
    const task = new Task(req.body);

    task.save().then(() => {
        res.status(201).send(task);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    });
});

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    User.find({}).then((users) => {
        res.send(users);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send();
    });
});

app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    const _id = req.params.id;

    User.findById(_id).then((user) => {
        if(!user){
            return res.status(404).send();
        }

        res.send(user);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send();
    });
});

app.get('/tasks', (req, res) => {
    Task.find({}).then((tasks) => {
        res.send(tasks);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send();
    });
});

app.get('tasks/:id', (req, res) => {
    const _id = req.params.id;

    Task.findById(_id).then((task) => {
        if(!task){
            return res.status(404).send();
        }

        res.send(task);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send();
    });
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is on port ' + port);
});
```

I have inserted tasks and they are showing up in Robo 3T - 1.3:
[image]

I am able to display all tasks in Postman as seen here:
[image]

But I am unable to search for a single ID:
[image]

It is return a 404 error which I set here:

```
Task.findById(_id).then((task) => {
    if(!task){
        return res.status(404).send();
    }

    res.send(task);
}).catch((e) => {
    res.status(500).send();
});
```

The ID is being copied directly from Robo 3T, yet isn't showing up.

ID from Robo 3T:

> ObjectId("5f22b25820e420212af69875")

So, I am searching for: 5f22b25820e420212af69875

By entering: localhost:3000/tasks/5f22b25820e420212af69875

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here? I have tried rewriting the code multiple times but can't come to a solution.

I apologize if my question is poorly worded, I am very new. Please don't hesitate to ask for anything that will help clarify my question. Tank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix it by adding a "/" to the front of my route:

```
app.get('/tasks/:id', (req, res) => {
    const _id = req.params.id;

    Task.findById(_id).then((task) => {
        if(!task){
            return res.status(404).send();
        }

        res.send(task);
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send();
    });
})
```